# Adding strings and not numbers in a calculator

Tags: javascript, numbers

I fairly new to JavaScript, and this code isn't very advanced. I was building a simple calculator with two inputs and a dropdown menu to choose an operation. Whenever I try to add the two inputs, it adds the strings instead. However, all of the other operations work. I think the problem comes in line 7: var total = n1 + n2; this might be adding the strings and not the numbers Any solutions?

```
        function calculate() {
                const n1 = document.getElementById("Num1").value;
                const n2 = document.getElementById("Num2").value;
                const e = document.getElementById("op");
                const oper = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
                   if (oper.normalize() === "+") {
                var total = n1 + n2;
            } else if (oper.normalize() === "-"){
                var total = n1 - n2;
            } else if (oper.normalize() === "*"){
                var total = n1 * n2;
            } else if (oper.normalize() === "/"){
                var total = n1 / n2;
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = total;
        }
    </script>
        <div style="background-color:rgb(225,225,225);border:1px solid black;margin-left:800px;margin-right:800px;"><br>
            <input id="Num1" placeholder="Input 1"><br><br>
                    <select id="op">
                        <option>+</option>
                        <option>-</option>
                        <option>*</option>
                        <option>/</option>
                    </select><br><br>
            <input id="Num2" placeholder="Input 2"><br><br>
            <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button><br><br>
        </div>
    <p style="color:red" id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used same code and it was working fine but if you are getting issue then please try to use parseInt(n1) to convert string to number

Comment: Im using Sublime text 3 and google chrome, so that might have been why it worked for you.